# Securely passing credentials for API authentication - Python 3

Tags: python, api, authentication, python-requests, restful-authentication

In Python 3, I'm passing credentials to authenticate an API call and it works completely fine using the following line:

```
userAndPass = b64encode(b"username:password").decode("ascii")
```

For security purposes, what I would prefer to do is store the credentials externally (possibly a yaml file or elsewhere) rather than hard code it. I attempted to replace the username and pass with variables, but that doesn't seem to work. I've tried placing the variable 'credentials' in brackets and also tried adding a plus before hand, neither work.

I would like it to work as follows:

```
credentials = "username:password"
userAndPass = b64encode(b'credentails').decode("ascii")
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requests` lets you pass an `auth` tuple, for example:

```
username = 'Antonio'
password = 'xx1234xx'
user_pass = (username, password)

res = requests.get('https://www.example.com/fetch', auth=user_pass)
```

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realise you could pass it in as a tuple!

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case you are passing the variable in a wrong way.

`b64encode(b'credentails')` means *encode the bytes array [c, r, e, d, e, n, t, i, a, l, s]*.

Use it like that:

`credentials = b"username:password"
userAndPass = b64encode(credentails).decode("ascii")`

#### EDIT:

In case you would like to obtain the credentials differently:

`credentials = somehow_get_credentials_as_string()
bytes_credentials = credentials.encode('utf-8') # or whatever the encoding is
userAndPass = b64encode(bytes_credentials).decode("ascii")`

Comment: Thanks, I have attempted this also, but the issue I was facing was to get the "username:password" string as a variable. I think the code example I provided in the question may have misled you. I'll edit it.

Comment: Although your EDIT may potentially work. Say credential = "username:pass", would the second line where you encode('utf-8') work the same as b"username:pass" ?

Comment: @Antonio yes and no. `b"string"` uses the encoding of the source code, `"string".encode('utf-8')` uses the provided encoding, so you have to handle it yourself (it basically means stick to one encoding and use it consistently when reading and writing the credentials).